# Associative Array does not work with eval() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I am generating a data expressed as a Python dictionary which is dumped using simplejson via url which is in this format.

```
{"2": "London", "3": "Tokyo", "4": "Sydney"}
```

I am using `$.get` and storing into a variable data.
However `eval(data)` does not generate an Associative Array. Actually throws up an error. What is the problem? What is the solution?

Edit: I have shared the code
http://dpaste.com/570901/

Comment: eval("console.info(" + JSON.stringify('{"2": "London", "3": "Tokyo", "4": "Sydney"}')+")");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` is slow, inefficient and hard to debug. Don't use it.

Have your script output an `application/json` content-type header, and jQuery will convert JSON to a JS object automatically.

Answer (score 9):

Your error is because a `{` at the beggining of a statement is read as a code block (like the kind you use in `if`s and `for`s) and not as an object literal. You can put parenthesis around for the eval to do as you want:

```
eval('(' + str + ')');
```

Of course, eval is evil and you should use something like `JSON.parse` instead. Most new browsers have this and it is not only safer but faster.

Comment: `eval` is not evil. `eval` has no moral compass and is in fact not sentient.

Comment: That only what it wants you to think. Eval is probably plotting the destruction of mankind as we speak!

Comment: We are planning world domination not destruction.... I mean.. (`eval` is so gonna kill me...)

Answer (score 6):

We need to see more code...

```
var x = '{"2": "London", "3": "Tokyo", "4": "Sydney"}';

eval('var y = ' + x);
      // or
var y = eval('(' + x + ')');

console.log(y);
console.log(y["2"]);
```

The above works just fine. What exactly are you doing/not doing?

PS: You shouldn't use `eval` for this regardless, but it's important to know how it works.

Comment: we don't need to see any more code.  Your code works because you're eval'ing something different than the OP.  See some of the other responses such as missingno for an explanation.

Comment: @jdigital: `eval(data)` is synchronous with `eval(x)` per above, I do hope you realize that

Comment: You are evaluating "var y = { ... }" whereas he is evaluating "{...}".  And I assume you mean "synonymous", not "synchronous" ;-)

Comment: @jdigital: I'm actually showing two ways of `eval`'ing a statement. Yes, synonymous :)

Comment: Yes but both are different than the OP.  In any case, the question has been answered by others without the need to see any additional code.  Perhaps I'm reading too much into your first and second sentences, so why not simply say "Here are two ways to make this work".

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you are evaluating JavaScript code and not JSON. From the looks of it your string will evaluate to a block but the first portion is syntactically incorrect. (`"2":` is close to a labeled statement but no cigar.) You'll need to wrap the string in parentheses to treat it as an object literal.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery's [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function, you can tell it to expect a json string back (set the 'dataType' as "json"), and it will take care of creating an object for you, no eval() required.